# Zend FrameWork 2 Album tutorial Error : A 404 error occurred Page not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am following the below tutorial to implement the [skeleton application][1].

I have copy-pasted all the code provided in the tutorial, but I am getting the below error:

> A 404 error occurred
>
> Page not found.
>
> The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
>
> No Exception available

I have cross checked all the similar issues in StackOverflow, but none of them were able to solve my issue.

Can some one help me in this?

Please find the below code.:

**`C:\wamp64\www\zend\module\Album\Module.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Album;

use Album\Model\AlbumTable;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
            ),
        );
    }    

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

C:\wamp64\www\zend\module\Album\config\module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Is there a way in zend to do a debug on where the issue is occurring?

.htaccess file includes the below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

vhost is as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zend
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/zend/public
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/zend/public/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

host is setup as

```
127.0.0.1       zend
```

I am trying to access the link as below

http://zend/album

C:\wamp64\www\zend\config\modules.config.php

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Album',
];
```

Comment: just needing to confirm but your using the Apache Web Server right? did you do what it said at the very bottom where it says *"if you see a standard Apache 404 error, then you need to fix .htaccess usage before continuing."*

Comment: what url did you input ? What's your vhost (wamp vhost)

Comment: Hi Memor-X and Hooli Thanks for the reply. I have added the .htaccess and vhost and host info to the question.Can you please see if its fine or not

Comment: [Did you register the module](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/modules.html#informing-the-application-about-our-new-module)?

Comment: HI Alex, I have added the code in modules.config where i have registered the module

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't the vhost in windows use \ insted of / so c:/wamp64/www/zend/public/ should be c:\wamp64\www\zend\public\ ?

Answer (score 2):

It was because of cache.

Just disabled the below in C:\wamp64\www\zend\config\application.config.php

```
'config_cache_enabled' => false,
'module_map_cache_enabled' => false
```

Comment: Man i lost 2 days for this stupid `404`. Thank you alot